# Populating Firestore database data into a table modular version 9

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to read Database Data into a Table but I am getting an empty table from my Output though I am convinced I am doing the right thing.
Below is My code in the useEffect Hook and how I am Calling the data in the Table data jsx element.

Intervening for your Help

My Use useEffect Code

```
useEffect(() => {

    const readCustomersData= async() =>{
        const data = await getDocs(customersCollectionRef);
        setCustomers(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id:doc.id})));

    }

    readCustomersData();
},[])
```

How I am Calling The code in The jsx Elememnt

```
             { customers.map(( value, index) => { 
                  return( 

                <tr key={index.id}>
                   
                    <th scope="row">{index+1}</th>
                    <td>{value.cname}</td>
                    <td>{value.contact}</td>
                    <td>{}</td>
                    <th>{}</th>
                    <td>{}</td>
                    <td>{}</td>
                    <td>{}</td>
                    <td>{}</td>

                    <td className='p-2 d-flex justify-content-space-between'>
                        <Button variant='success'>Update</Button> <Button variant='danger'>Delete</Button>
                       
                    </td>
                </tr>


                  )
              })}

                   
                    
                   
            </tbody>
```

Comment: What did you do to debug your code? What is the size of the QuerySnapshot? (i.e. `data.size`). What is the code of `setCustomers`?

Comment: sorry,  but I dont Your question, my setCustomers code is the useEffect code

Comment: Ok, my mistake! But what is the size of the QuerySnapshot? Do you receive some docs from Firestore?

Comment: Yea I should be receiving because My form is adding the data and I can See it on the Backend part of it.

Comment: But what do you see in the browser console if you do `const data = await getDocs(customersCollectionRef); console.log(data.size):`?

Comment: I get 3 as a result because i have 3 docs in my firestore

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240669/discussion-between-maxwel-ochieng-and-renaud-tarnec).